# Spinning icon on JQuery setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have a slide in search box, and to search the products I call this function:

```
$('#json_search').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutP);
    $('#search-resultlist').append('<li class="testicon"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></li>');
    timeoutP = setTimeout(searchItem, 1000);

});
```

This just calls a function which loads a partial html page:

```
var searchItem = function() {
    if($('#json_search').val())
    {
        $('#search-resultlist').load('/search/quick/q/'+ $('#json_search').val() );
    }
    else {
        $('#search-resultlist').html('');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="right-searchcontent" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ... " id="json_search">
             </div>
             <div class="right-searchresult">
                 <ul id="search-resultlist" >
                     <li >

                     </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
```

Now the spinning icon shows up when I start searching, but it shows a new icon everytime I press a key,and I just want it to show up 1 time.
Anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually 'solved' this in this way:

```
function loadIcon(){
        $('#loading-indicator').show();
    }


var counterIcon = 0;
     $('#json_search').keyup(function() {
        if($('#json_search').val() == '') {
            $('#loading-indicator').hide();
            counterIcon = 0;
        }
        counterIcon++;
        clearTimeout(timeoutP);

        if(counterIcon = 1) {
            setTimeout(loadIcon, 100);
        }
        timeoutP = setTimeout(searchItem, 2000);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use temp class for detect first search.

```
$('#json_search').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutP);
    if (!$(this).hasClass('sameClass')){
    $('#search-resultlist').append('<li class="testicon"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></li>');
    }
    timeoutP = setTimeout(searchItem, 1000);

});

var searchItem = function() {
    if($('#json_search').val())
    {
        $('#search-resultlist').load('/search/quick/q/'+ $('#json_search').val() );
    }
    else {
        $('#search-resultlist').html('');
    }
    $('#json_search').addClass('sameClass')
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, this answer is not related now.